# Tag UITableViewCell automatically deleted when posting question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-synonym-process

Now I tried to post a new SO question. Another time the tag [uitableviewcell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewcell) was removed when I posted the question. Do you also have the problem?

Answer (score 6):

It is a synonym of [uitableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview), meaning that when you use it, it gets replaced by the "synonym parent".

Comment: I am curious as to why that's the case. A table view cell is not the same thing as a table view. One could have a question about a custom cell that's not at all related to its containing table view. Note that both [tag:uicollectionview] and [tag:uicollectionviewcell] exist.